# Adding a Java unfinished project to SBT dependencies

Tags: java, scala, dependencies, sbt

I am new in SBT and I am thinking in migrating my work to IntellijIDEA.

I have a Java project that I created using eclipse and now I want to use it with scala.

However, that Java project is constantly changing and I don't want to compile every single time a jar and put in lib folder.

Is there a simple way to add this dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you have two projects:

1) In `/main-project`, you have `build.sbt` containing the line `name := "main-project-id"`

2) In `/other-project`, you have `build.sbt` containing the line `name := "other-project-id"`

You can create a dependency from the Main project to the Other project by adding the file `/main-project/project/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MainProjectBuild extends Build {
  lazy val main = Project(id = "main-project-id", base = file(".")) dependsOn(other)
  lazy val other = Project(id = "other-project-id", base = file("other-project"))
}
```

And then adding a link to `/other-project` inside of `/main-project`.  Something like:

```
cd /main-project
ln -s ../other-project other-project
```

so that you now have a `other-project` in a directory called: `/main-project/other-project/`.

Having done this, if you run `sbt compile` or whatever inside `/main-project`, it will work as expected.

**EDIT**

A different, perhaps simpler way would just be to create a link to your java sources that makes it look like they are in the same source directory.

So if your Scala code is in `/main-project/src/main/scala/somepackage/...` and your java code is in `/other-project/src/main/java/otherpackage/...`, then you could do:

```
cd /main-project/src/main
ln -s /other-project/src/main/java java
```

then the directory `/main-project/src/main/java` will just be pointing to the dependency source, but sbt will build it all together.

Comment: Hmm... It is really necessary to create another build.sbt or just pointing out the directory works? Also, do I really need to move the folder to the `main-project/` folder?

Comment: @Tiago, Edited with a possibly simpler idea

Comment: I have to call ln all time I want to work? Doesn't seem simpler. And I still have the problem that I have to move the project location. But probly I don't want to complicate. I will try to move to Intellij and let's see. Thanks for both options.

Comment: @Tiago, the `ln` command creates a symbolic link.  You only have to do it once, and from then on the file system will see the source folder as appearing in two different places at the same time, so you won't need to move the original.

Comment: Ah, but I am not working on linux :). Eitherway, I generated the IntelliijIDEA file and it seems that this didn't work :(

Comment: @Tiago, Yeah, windows doesn't having linking, so it's not quite so simple.  So good options would be: moving the dependency into a subfolder and doing the first option.  Or, configuring the dependency in IntelliJ.  I, personally, use Eclipse, and configuring dependencies is very easy; I would assume it's also easy to configure in IntelliJ, but I don't know how.

Comment: Ok. It doesn't work even forgetting IDEs. SBT compiles however when I try to use a class from other-project it doesn't work.